# How do I find the .jar file for minecraft? [1.12]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I cannot find this file. A lot of people say that there is a .bin folder, but there is none on my pc.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

By default there is a folder at `%APPDATA%\.minecraft\versions` (Yes, that's a working folder path.), there's a folder named after the version number and there's the .jar file.

If you set your Minecraft folder to somewhere else using the launcher, then it's in the `versions` folder in that folder.